# How to set up guest/ethernet/fiber network

Tags: firewall, subnet, vlan, pfsense

I have a pretty basic network but I'm wanting to make some changes to it and I would like to know what the best way would be to achieve this.

Currently:
I have the internet come in to the modem to the router to the switch to all wired devices and an AP for the wireless devices.

What I would like:
I am going to add a second AP for guest access. (The reason for this is so they can brows freely while being completely separate from my home network and I can limit their usage if I need to.) I do not want them to be able to access the devices on my main network but I do want them to be able to access the same internet.

I would also like to add a 5Gb fiber connection for my main PC and my server to use for communication between each other as I frequently transfer large amounts of files between the two. I do not want this fiber connection to have access to the internet. I also do not want either device to try to go through the other to access the internet as they will already have their own connection that they should be using. (Note: I am willing to bypass the switch and connect the two directly if I need to but I would prefer to go through the switch.)

I am sure we will need to use subnets, VLANS, firewall settings, or a combination of the three to accomplish what I'm wanting to do. I am very knowledgeable in both of these as I work doing VOIP support and managed services for VERY large companies but this will be the first time I will be setting one up from scratch so I'm not sure what best practice would be to accomplish what I'm wanting. Given the option I prefer subnets over VLANS.

I am sure these questions will come up so I will try to answer most of them below.
Modem is an Arris cable modem.
Router is a Linksys EA6900 but will be replaced with a custom rack mount PFSense router.
Managed switch is a 48 port Netgear GS748Tv3

Below is a basic diagram to hopefully explain what I would like to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Your diagram pointing to a black hole... Could you provide a workable link? BTW, what is your question about, I mean what help are you looking for?

Comment: My question is two fold.

I am looking for advise on setting up the guest network where they can access the internet but not any devices on the main network.

I am also looking on how to set up the fiber network to prioritize communication between the two devices but not allow communication through the devices.

The link works but says it will be available momentarily.

Comment: You do realize that subnets offer no actual isolation whatsoever, right?

Comment: You mentioned you would use pFsense. You can get multiports ethernet cards and physically separate networks. For example guest WiFi shouldn't be on the same switch as LAN, but on its own interface. Make multiple LANs on pFsense and set there routing rules who can talk to each other or just merely get access to internet only. Put on separate network device from data mining company if u care abt privacy

Comment: Thanks Alex. That's what I wanted to hear. I figured that had to be configured in the router and had to have a second ethernet run. I would still want it to go through the same switch though. Would you do that with subnets or VLANs? Also, do you have any advice on the fiber run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Guest network: The simplest way to set this up is on your main router, where you use firewall rules to ensure the segment with the guest AP is separate from the segment with your internal network (both LAN and WLAN). So you'll have two segments (and a third segment for the fiber connection).

I'm not familiar with pfSense, only with iptables, so I can't give details, but it's a fairly standard setup where basically you have to add rules that allow forwarding between the network adapters for guest/internet and internal/internet, but disallow guest/internal.

If you cannot connect the Guest AP directly to the router, but only to the switch, you'll need a VLAN that makes it appear as if it was directly connected to the router.

Note your custom rack will not only have to route and firewall, but also provide services like DHCP, DNS proxy/cache etc. Home routers include all this, and also often already have a ready-made guest network configuration, so research if you really need a custom rack, and if it comes with everything you need. Another option is to replace the firmware on your home router with OpenWRT etc.

2) Fiber between PC and server: I'd expect the Netgear to support configuration of "port groups" or something similar that only talk to each other. Make one such group for the two fiber ports, and another group for the rest. If the Netgear can't do that, use VLAN on the fiber. A different segment for the fiber means you can choose the transfer route by choosing the destination address.

3) The WLAN interface of your internal AP should be bridged to the LAN interface (depending on the AP firmware, this has various names). This will mean that your central DHCP server on the router can handle both, and it will also mean your LAN and WLAN can share a single segment, and see each other.

Answer (score 1):

I heard that it better to see once instead of read hundred times, so below is my suggestions:

[image: net]

[pFsense](https://www.pfsense.org/) is really powerful enterprise level flexible solution, so you can utilize practically anything on it. If you will use a regular PC as a home for your [pFsense](https://www.pfsense.org/), you can find some decent multiport ethernet cards something like [image: this]

I suggest you to use Intel base cards (like Intel PRO/1000...) for maximum compatibility with FreeBSD (OS behind [pFsense](https://www.pfsense.org/)).

This way you can physically split network to multiple subnets that can be isolated or can talk between each other depending on your needs by configuring firewall/routing on [pFsense](https://www.pfsense.org/). While VLANs are cheap, there could be a cases when some clients equipment doesn't support it, so separating subnets physically like OPT1 and LAN on the picture above will reduce in a future PITA.

As about fiber link, get a couple fiber cards and install it on the server and your main PC and connect them directly. If you wouldn't setup bridge between ethernet and fiber interfaces on your main PC then you server will be accessible to this PC only.
I suggest you to go with 10Gb link. If you would shop on ebay, you can find very cheap(to compare with brand new) used equipment. If you would go with Intel 82599 Chipset based cards, you wouldn't have problem, just keep in mind, to compare to Ethernet cards, fiber ones are real Zoo, where cards has the same slot for fiber modules but incompatible between each other (for example SFP+ netgear module can fit in socket on Intel base cards but wouldn't work.).
Also go with fiber cables that has cyan color if distance between your PC and server are matter.

Answer (score 0):

For actual isolation, you need either VLANs or multiple network interfaces.

I’ll talk about VLANs, because they’re cheap and easy to implement:

- VLAN 1: Regular network
- VLAN 2: Guest network

I’ll just describe the target configuration.

- On your firewall/router box,

  - VLAN 1 and 2 are set up.
  - the LAN network interface is set to use tagged VLANs (sometimes called trunk)
  - VLAN 1 is assigned to the “internal network” zone
  - VLAN 2 is assigned to the “guest network” zone
  - firewall/forwarding rules are set up as appropriate
- On your managed switch,

  - the firewall/router is connected to port 1
  - the guest AP is connected to port 2
  - port 1 is member of VLAN 1 & 2, tagged
  - port 2 is member of VLAN 2, untagged
  - all other ports are members of VLAN 1, untagged

This will result in an isolated guest network. Traffic from the guest network will be isolated as set up on the firewall.

Your switch does not support 5 GBit/s Ethernet in any way.